# Deployment - Error: You can't use the Large form factor with a Lightning component action override

Tags: lightning-aura-components, deployment

Has anyone encountered this on v42.0 and if so, was there a resolution? I am overriding the "New" Case action with a Lightning component.

Strangely enough, when attempting to deploy to an org that org on API v41.0, the message is instead: `objects/Case.object -- Error: Large is not a supported form factor.`

In the Case.object metadata, here is the relevant action override section (you can see formFactor is indeed set to "large":

```
<actionOverrides>
    <actionName>NewCase</actionName>
    <content>CreateCaseCmp</content>
    <formFactor>Large</formFactor>
    <skipRecordTypeSelect>false</skipRecordTypeSelect>
    <type>LightningComponent</type>
</actionOverrides>
```

However, a value of "large" seems to be what the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/actionoverride.htm) for the actionOverride metadata requires for a lightning component override -

> the Large value represents the Lightning Experience desktop
>   environment and is only valid for the flexipage and lightningcomponent
>   types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was testing and removing the `<formFactor>Large</formfactor>` line from the metadata allowed the deploy to succeed, and the override **appears** to be working correctly in the target org.

Comment: What tool did you use to remove the element from the XML? We tried using Copado, its Find and Replace Rule, with a Perl-based regex expression: `(?s)(\n\s*<formFactors>Small</formFactors>)`. We also unsuccessfully tried to Find and Replace just the exact element `<formFactors>Small</formFactors>`.